# How to get equal distance planes from a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, machine-learning, plane-geometry

I have 3 parallel planes and the normal vector 'W'(A,B,C) and this is normal to all the 3 planes.

[3D planes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BV3fL.png)

Top plane equation is Ax+By+Cz+D=k

Middle plane equation is  Ax+By+Cz+D=0

Below plane equation is  Ax+By+Cz+D=-k

How to prove that that Top and Below planes are equal distance from middle plane?

Comment: There are quite a few ways. What are you allowed to use? What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: @amd There are no constraints on this problem.

Comment: @amd lets say we have point v1 on top plane and v2 on middle plane then length(v2-v1) is the distance between above plane and middle plane.
projection of vector v2-v1  onto normal vector is length .
Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick any point on the middle plane.

I would pick $P(0,0,-D/C)$ assuming that $C\ne 0$

Use the distance from P to the other planes.

$$ d_1 = \frac {|0+0+C(-D/C)+D-k|}{\sqrt {A^2+B^2+C^2}} =\frac {|-k|}{\sqrt {A^2+B^2+C^2}}$$

$$d_2=  \frac {|0+0+C(-D/C)+D+k|}{\sqrt {A^2+B^2+C^2}}= \frac {|k|}{\sqrt {A^2+B^2+C^2}}$$

Thus $d_1=d_2$

Comment: Thank you so much , I got a clear Idea.

Comment: @RaviGurnatham Note that if we are given and we can refer to the formula for the distance the problem becomes trivial. Check if it is the case. Otherwise we need to follow some others method or to derive the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Since the distance between parallel planes is measured perpendicularly to them, you could take any line that’s parallel to the common normal of these planes, compute its intersection with them, and compare distances. However, this problem can be solved by inspection.

Rewrite the equations in the form $W\cdot(x,y,z) = k$. The left-hand side is equal to $\|W\|$ times the (signed) length of the projection of $(x,y,z)$ onto $W$, and the distance of these planes from the origin is measured parallel to $W$, so the constant term in these equations is proportional to the distances of the planes from the origin. The differences between the constant terms of the equations of the two outer planes and the middle one are $\pm k$, so these planes are the same distance from the central one.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

A simple way is to proceed as follow

- consider the line through the origin with direction vector $v=(A,B,C)$ and therefore perpendicular to the planes that is

$$(x,y,z)=t(A,B,C)$$

- find the intersection points $P$ and $Q$ between the line and the top and below plane
- compute the distances $OP$ and $OQ$

A shorter alternative is to consider the dot product between any vector $OP=(x,y,z)$ on the plane with the normal unitary vector to the plane $\hat n=(a,b,c)$ and observe that

$$|(x,y,z)\cdot (a,b,c)|=|ax+by+cz|$$

represents the distance between the plane and the origin.

This kind of approach leads to the formula for the distance between $P_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and a plane $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$

$$d_{\pi P_0}=\frac{|Ax_0+By_0+C_0z+D|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}}$$

Comment: lets say we have point v1 on top plane and v2 on middle plane then length(v2-v1) is the distance between above plane and middle plane. projection of vector v2-v1 onto normal vector is length . Am I correct?

Comment: @RaviGurnatham We need that the vector $v_1-v_2$ is pependicular to the planes.

Comment: Yes ,I do agree with your point. what if we assume  v1-v2 is perpendicular to the plane.

Comment: @RaviGurnatham Well done! Note that we can assume for $v_2$ the origin to make derivation simpler.

Comment: @RaviGurnatham If you want to show your work in the OP for the resolution I can take a look to that.